# Accessing objects in PHP like in Java

Tags: java, php, oop, object

I've spent the last few months knee deep in Java and I'm just re-visiting PHP. In Java I can create an array of objects and access the methods like so:

```java
Jam jam = new Jam(1,"strawberry","December","false");
//creates an object with an id, a flavour, a useby and an opened status
```

So if I loop through to create some jams, I might have an array something like

```java
[0] => [id => 1,"stawberry"... etc
[1] => [id => 2, "raspberry"... etc]
```

Now my jam model might have a method like

```java
update_opened(bool newStatus) {
   this.openedStatus = newStatus;
}
```

So now I can loop through my jams and call the method

```
for(...size of array) {
    if(i == 1) {
       array.get(i).update_opened(true);
    }

}
```

And now my jam gets opened. I can pass this object around my application and access the method whenever I want/need

In PHP this doesn't seem to happen. I seem to need to recreate a new set of objects each time such as:

```php
array_map(function($j) use ($jams) {
     $j = new jam(....);
     if($j->id == 1) $j->updateOpenedStatus(true);
     return $jams[$j->id] = $j;
     },
$jams);
```

Should I need to do this or should my objects still stand in the same way? I'm wondering if this is because Java is a compiled language rather than just a simple run-time style like PHP, but I don't know if that makes sense at all. If anyone can shed some light on this it would be really useful, to help my understanding of how the language works on a deeper level.

(P.S. I'm not really doing an application based on Jam, that would be delicious)

Comment: I don't follow, what is the `jam` class, does it have `id` and is it set somewhere? In your function you attempt to use `$locations`, `$l` and `$ul` where do those come from???

Comment: Also, you're passing in `$j` but then defining `$j` as a new `jam` and you `use($jams)` but never actually use it.  Maybe a bulleted list of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @AbraCadaver - yes sorry, i'm doing a real life problem ad tried to make it into a generic example and missed a some of the references. My questionis not really about the functions themselves and if things assign correctly etc - the code posted is demonstrative - the point is, in java I can create an object once, and pass it into an array and later use that objects methods, but I don't seem to be able to do this in php.  It's not so much about the code as it is about the theoretical application of php objects vs java objects

Comment: @AbraCadaver also this is really my point in a nutshell 'Also, you're passing in $j but then defining $j as a new jam' <-- you are right, i seem to have to make a new 'jam' each time, passing the properties of my exisiting jam.  In java i can just access the existing object's methods, but it doesn't work the same way in php

Comment: Any follow-up to this?

Comment: @AbraCadaver if i remember rightly, the cause of the issue was actually that in another part of the program I was referring to the wrong variable and I had looked at it for so long i was unable to see it.  So in short, what we call in my current team `Bad Programming`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I was bored waiting on something, here's a starting point ([Executable Demo](https://3v4l.org/e2rvM)):

```
//define the jam class
class jam {
    public $id;
    public $flavour;
    public $useby;
    public $openedStatus;

    public function __construct($id, $flavour, $useby, $openedStatus) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->flavour = $flavour;
        $this->useby = $useby;
        $this->openedStatus = $openedStatus;
    }

    public function updateOpenedStatus($newStatus) {
        $this->openedStatus = $newStatus;
    }

}

//create an array of objects with different properties
$jams[] = new jam(1, "strawberry", "december", false);
$jams[] = new jam(2, "raspberry", "november", false);

//loop the array and change the first object
foreach($jams as $jam) {
    if($jam->id == 1) {
       $jam->updateOpenedStatus(true);
    }
}

var_dump($jams);
```

This yields (notice the first object with `id=1` reflects the new `openedStatus=true`):

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(jam)#1 (4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["flavour"]=>
    string(9) "stawberry"
    ["useby"]=>
    string(8) "december"
    ["openedStatus"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  [1]=>
  object(jam)#2 (4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["flavour"]=>
    string(9) "raspberry"
    ["useby"]=>
    string(8) "november"
    ["openedStatus"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
}
```

Where is the confusion?

Comment: thanks - there's no confusion, this is what I expected but my objects are not allowing me to access the methods when I've put them into an array and tried to access them later on.  As I'm not getting any errors anywhere I wanted to check I wasn't misunderstanding what I was trying to do and trying to use Java structures in PHP.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can define an array of objects, use a `foreach` loop and call the method on each object in the collection. No difference with Java.

```
$jams = array();
$jams[] = new Jam(1, "strawberry","December",false);
$jams[] = new Jam(2, "raspberry", "January", true);

foreach($jams as $jam){
    if($jam->id == 1)
        $jam->updateOpenedStatus(true);
}
```

Comment: `$j` should be `$jam`